# Problems with eval and use

Tags: perl, module, detect, strict, bareword

I wrote this code and it works when POE module is installed in the system.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POE;

...
```

But I want to determine if this module exist:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
eval("use POE; 1") or die ('Please, install POE module. \n');

...
```

and it returns:

```
Bareword "KERNEL" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./terminalhero.perl line 58.
Bareword "HEAP" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./terminalhero.perl line 60.
Execution of ./terminalhero.perl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I tried other modules and also had errors. How can I do what I want using strict mode?

Comment: What is the contents of `terminalhero.perl`?  Especially lines 58 and 60.

Comment: Please repost the code. SO becomes useless if the references are gone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that eval runs after compile time, but your `KERNEL` and `HEAP` constants are checked at compile time.  So you need to put your eval inside of a BEGIN block:

```
BEGIN {
    eval "use POE;";
    die "Unable to load POE: $@\n" if $@;
}
```

Although this is mostly an exercise in futility, because a standard `use POE;` will also die with a useful error if it can't load the module you've requested.

Comment: This way, if the program were feeling devilishly proactive, it could automatically download and ask to install the missing module. But that might cause more harm than good, really.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Yes, if you're doing something other than dying, it can make sense.

Comment: I wouldn't call the standard error message useful. Compare with the one [provided by perl5i](http://p3rl.org/perl5i#Better-load-errors).

Comment: @daxim: I think it is useful... friendly on the other hand... it could use a fair amount of improvement in the friendly department. :)